# Single page website with jQuery - Content in JS or HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm just picking up JS & jQuery and consider myself quite capable with HTML/CSS. I'm in the middle of building a single page front-end only website. I've got the layout nailed down with Bootstrap and now I'm just trying to figure out some of the functionality. My scenario is as follows:

There are 4 `<div>`s with text and an image in each of the 4 `<div>`s; and there is a `<div>` with class `#content` below it. There is a `.on('click')` listener for each of the `#c1-4` divs and when the user clicks on a particular div, the `#content` div will change accordingly.

```
<div id="#c1" class="active-div">
    <p>Text Here</p>
    <img src="image.jpg">
</div>

<div id="#c2">
    <p>Text 2 Here</p>
    <img src="image2.jpg">
</div>

<div id="#c3">
    <p>Text 3 Here</p>
    <img src="image3.jpg">
</div>

<div id="#c4">
    <p>Text 4 Here</p>
    <img src="image4.jpg">
</div>

<div id="#content">
    <!-- Content of the selected div goes here -->
</div>
```

By default, `#c1 <div>` is selected. The content that goes in to `#content` is mostly text but some icons and images too, with appropriate styling.

**The Question:** What is the best way to store & load content into the `#content` div? Based on my knowledge so far I believe the options are:

1. Hard-coding it into the JS and using `.html()` to set the content; although this would add quite a bit of HTML to the JS.
2. Hard-coding 4 different divs related to each of the 4 `#c` IDs and using `.show()` and `.hide()` accordingly.
3. Using `.load()` to load the content from another HTML document. However, I'm not sure how styling would be handled and how this will affect the display of the `#content` div.

I would also like to know the pros and cons of each of the above approaches and which one would be more suitable for future maintenance (e.g. adding a fifth, sixth `#c` numbered div to select & load content for).

Comment: I would just add a div within each of the `#c1-4` divs with the content, hide those divs and then when you click on one, the html of `#content` is replaced with the html of the hidden content div associated with the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

In real world developers consider backend data to replace / append content based on user's clicks and it is just second thing how exactly you append / prepend / html or load your content to your div element. Not sure how you are going to hardcode different content according to the clicked button, I think in your case #2 & #3 should do the trick.
There is append / prepend actions you can use (they are self-explanatory I guess, but might be useful in some cases).
As I mentioned initially in ideal work you will do queries to your backend endpoints (databases, API etc..) and fetch content from there. Once done, you just style it accordingly using those divs and css (either inline or CSS table) things. Focus on overall construction!

Comment: Yup I'm aware of backend interaction as I'm just starting out with Node.js and MongoDB. However this particular project does not require dynamically changing data nor a backend to even be built as the content will not be changed for quite some time; which is also why I've decided to make it a purely front-end endeavour

Comment: Understood! So, those 2&3 and may be my fifty cents should be correct answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways to do this and a lot of JS frameworks out there that do it differently, but all of your options are appropriate in my opinion, especially given that you're using jQuery.  I'll just talk a bit about your three options:

1. You can hard-code it into your JS, but you can also place the content in your HTML in a `<script>` tag and load it as a JavaScript string in jQuery, like they do for Underscore templates.

   ```
   <script type="text/template" id="div-1">
       <span>Hey, this is some content</span>
   </script>
   ```

   Then later in your JavaScript, just do `$('#div-1').html()` to get the contents of it, and you can stick that in your content div.
2. This option is also perfectly acceptable.
3. As long as you have all your css already applied to the document, dynamically changing the DOM won't affect its ability to apply styles.  Just make sure you have all the rules in a stylesheet that is already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, here is how you could do it with hidden content divs and replacing html using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```js
$(function() {
  var content = $('.active-div .content').html();
  $('#content').html(content);

  $('.item').click(function() {
    $('.item').removeClass('active-div');
    $(this).addClass('active-div');
    content = $('.active-div .content').html();
    $('#content').html(content);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  display:inline-block;
  padding-right:10px;
}
.content {
  display: none;
}
#content {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item active-div" id="#c1">
  <p>Text Here</p>
  <img src="image.jpg">
  <div class="content">Sample content 1</div>
</div>

<div class="item" id="#c2">
  <p>Text 2 Here</p>
  <img src="image2.jpg">
  <div class="content">Sample content 2</div>
</div>

<div class="item" id="#c3">
  <p>Text 3 Here</p>
  <img src="image3.jpg">
  <div class="content">Sample content 3</div>
</div>

<div class="item" id="#c4">
  <p>Text 4 Here</p>
  <img src="image4.jpg">
  <div class="content">Sample content 4</div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <!-- Content of the selected div goes here -->
</div>
```